# pyspark: how do you convert a column from a string to a categorical variable?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have let's say education level as a column.
It's a string.  How would you convert this to a categorical type of variable?  Is this necessary in pyspark, because in pandas, I'm told that categorical data is much faster to process.

```
df = df.withColumn("BIRTHDAY", df['BIRTHDAY'].cast(DateType()))
```

That's how I'd do a `string` to a `date`.